# Question regarding proof environment with bigcap and bigcup

Tags: math-mode

When I use `proof` environment, the `\bigcap` and `\bigcup` become regular `\cap` and `\cup`. I wonder is this a bug? and how can I work around this issue? Thank you.

[image]

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
        Give a careful proof of the second DeMorgan's laws, given on page 26 
        $$\bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}\bigg)^{c} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}^c$$
        for sets $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{n} \subseteq S$.
    \begin{proof}
        Assume $x \in \bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}\bigg)^{c} \implies x \not\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}
        \implies x \not\in E_i, \forall i, 1 \leq i \leq n \implies x \in E_i^c, \forall i, 1 \leq i \leq n$
        $\implies x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}^c$. Therefore $\bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}\bigg)^{c} =
        \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}^c$.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but these aren't "regular" `\cap` and `\cup`.  you would see the difference if you input, say `$\bigcap_{i-1}^n E_i \cap x$`.  the reason for the smaller versions of `\bigcap` and `\bigcup` in text is to avoid unevenly spaced baselines, which make a page look un-beautiful, and could make the text less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default setting for inline mathmode (when using `$ ... $`). The math operators are larger in `\displaystyle` (when using `\[ ... \]`) than they are in `\textstyle` or inline math mode.

If you want the operators to expand to their full height, use `\displaystyle\bigcup`. Note, however, that the limits also be typeset over the top/bottom, rather than the sides.